# How not to print the last separator character in StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, datagridview, character, streamwriter

I want to remove last character "|" from each row. I dont want to have last column closed with that character. Can you help?

```
private void spremiUDatotekuToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new
        System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName);

        for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; x++)
        {

            for (int y = 0; y < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; y++)
            {
                sw.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value);
                if (y != dataGridView1.Columns.Count)
                {
                    sw.Write("|");                    
                }
            }
            sw.WriteLine();
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this `sw.Write("|");`? I'm not sure what you are trying to ask here. You should carefully elaborate what your situation is, and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: To gain some speed, I would recommend you to export the data from the DataSet or DataTable. Other than that, solution from @rae1n is fine.

Comment: I believe OP wants to print `|` but only for inside the elements, not at the end of the row; in other words, OP wants `1|2|3|4|5`, not `1|2|3|4|5|`, which is what is currently printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are losing the last row from the code because you use "<" and "Count-1". This is the working code that also does what you want with the "|" and does not lose the last row:

```
private void spremiUDatotekuToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new
    System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName);

    for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; x++)
    {

        for (int y = 0; y < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; y++)
        {
            sw.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value);
            if (y != dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1) // Count - 1 is the last value. y will never reach count because you have "<" sign
            {
                sw.Write("|");                    
            }
        }
        sw.WriteLine();
    }
    sw.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: If i have 1 row in datagrid, it will save 0 rows of data to text file because row -1 is needed here. Columns.Count -1 only does that last column isnt saved , if i want to save 5 columns, now only 4 will be saved, with | at the end too..

Comment: Where exactly is row-1 needed ? And where do you see that the last column is not saved in the file ? That if condition applies only to the separator. When y equals count - 1 (which is the last index in the columns collection) you wont't print the srparator. If you have 1 row, only rows(0) is saved.

Comment: Sorry, but without row count -1 it prints another non existing row with "| | | |" .. so i built solution with your code but kept row count at -1 and it works , thank you!

Comment: I understand, this happens because you have a row at the end with empty columns that you obviously don't want to print. Glad you were able to make it work;

Answer (score 2):

Try `dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1` instead,

```
if (y != dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
{
    sw.Write("|");                    
}
```

That way it won't print `|` after the last element on that row, which is when `y == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1`.

Alternatively, like @DaveZych mentions, you could user `string.Join` to avoid checking iterators and end with something like this,

```
foreach (var row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var rowValue = string.Join("|", row.Cells.Select(cell => cell.Value));
    sw.Write(rowValue);    
}

sw.Close();
```

Comment: I've already tried it. Columns.Count -1 only does that last column isn't saved , if i want to save 5 columns, now only 4 will be saved, with "|" at the end too..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking `y` against the `count`, you should check it against `count - 1`

```
if (y != dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
{
     sw.Write("|");                    
}
```

You're looping from `y < count` which means that y will never be equal to `count`.

Alternatively, you could use `string.Join` on the entire row:

```
for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; x++)
{
    string line = string.Join("|", dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells.Select(c => c.Value);
    sw.WriteLine(line);
}
```

This will create a string with all values delimited by `|`.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: At the top of the file, add a `using` statement for `System.Linq`, e.g. `using System.Linq;`